# Check if certain operators are being used in a function

Tags: python, operators

I want to prohibit certain operators being used in a function, for example, say I want to make sure the `**` power operator is not being used in the following function:

```
def pow(x, y):
    return x ** y
```

I have used `inspect.getsource` to get the source and checked if `"**"` is in the source but that will wrongly cause an assert error if there happens to be `"**"` in the source elsewhere  so how to actually check the code for the existence of a particular operator?

Comment: I think you would have to put in a dummy class instance, in which the forbidden operations (e.g., __pow__) raise an exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd personally go for Ashwini's answer if you have 3.4 at hand, however, if you need to be a bit more compatible and don't mind parsing the source, then you can make use of `ast`, eg:

```
import inspect
import ast

def pow(x, y):
    return x ** y

nodes = ast.walk(ast.parse(inspect.getsource(pow)))
has_power = any(isinstance(node, ast.Pow) for node in nodes)
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7, I should have specified. This is exactly what I was looking for, I had looked at `ast.walk` but was missing the `ast.parse` to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

**Note:** Byte code we are dealing with here is a CPython implementation detail. Don't expect it to work on other implementations of Python. Prefer [Jon Clements's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878033/846892).

---

In CPython 3.4+ you can use [`dis.get_instructions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions) to check if [`BINARY_POWER`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_POWER) instruction is present in function's code object or not(Also explained in [What's new in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#dis) doc):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def search_instruction(code_object, instr_code):
        for ins in dis.get_instructions(code_object):
            if ins.opcode == instr_code:
                return True
        return False
... 
>>> def f1():                                       
    s = x ** 2
...     
>>> def f2():
    s = 'x ** 2'
...     
>>> dis.opmap['BINARY_POWER']
19
>>> search_instruction(f1.__code__, 19)
True
>>> search_instruction(f2.__code__, 19)
False
```

---

For CPython 2.X specifically you can try [`byteplay`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/byteplay/0.2) package available on PyPI(its Python 3 fork: https://github.com/serprex/byteplay).:

```
>>> import byteplay
>>> def search_instruction(code_object, instr_code):
        for ins, _ in byteplay.Code.from_code(code_object).code:
                if ins == instr_code:
                    return True
        return False
...     
>>> search_instruction(f1.__code__, 19)
True
>>> search_instruction(f2.__code__, 19)
False
```

---

<sub>Related: [Bytecode: What, Why, and How to Hack it - Dr. Ryan F Kelly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve7lLHtJ9l8)</sub>

Comment: cheers, I should have specified it was for python 2.7 but the answer will be useful to others no doubt, I could not find any related question on SO.

Comment: `dis` is not available in some python implementations.  `ast` is better choice.

Comment: @wim Cool. Add a note about it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using the [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module?:

```
In [9]: dis.dis(pow)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 BINARY_POWER
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

You probably need to [redirect stdout to a stringIO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14707227/1007990) to parse it in Python<3.4